# Configuring different physical DBs for same datasource in two JBoss applications

Tags: datasource, jboss6.x

I want to deploy the same Java EE enterprise application twice (under two different names)in a JBoss 6.0 server instance.
Both of these applications use the same logical datasource as configured in the server.
No problem so far.

Yet, I'd like to target each of the two applications a different physical database through this one and only logical datasource.

Is that possible with JBoss 6.0 somehow (without using two different server instances or changing the application before deployment or packaging different *ds.xml files in each application?)

Answer (score 0):

> (without using two different server instances or changing the
>   application before deployment or packaging different *ds.xml files in
>   each application?)

Two different data sources under the same *-ds.xml file:

```
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>DS1</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://db.server/db?</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>pass</password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
<metadata>
    <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
</metadata>
</local-tx-datasource>
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>DS2</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://com.db/db2?</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>pass</password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
<metadata>
   <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
</metadata>
</local-tx-datasource>
```

The only downside is that you have to customize your code if you are using the @Resource annotation:

```
@Resource(mappedName="DS2")
private DataSource ds;
```

Haven't tried the following, but you might be able to do a explicit JNDI lookup via InitialContext, and specify the resource to be looked up in a properties file (DS1 / DS2)? If you are using Maven (I am making multiple assumptions now :)) you could [filter the properties file](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files) and provide the right DB datasource name via profiles during build time.